# Move files from bucket to another bucket/folder

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto, aws-sdk

I want to move files from a bucket, to the same bucket/folder.

The `test` folder already exists.

```
srcBucket = "tmp"
dstBucket = "tmp"
import boto
c = boto.connect_s3()
src = c.get_bucket(srcBucket)
dst = c.get_bucket(dstBucket)
print dst
for k in src.list():
# copy stuff to your destination here
    dst.copy_key(k.key, src.name, "/test/"+k.key)
```

I am getting:

```
<Message>The specified key does not
exist.</Message><Key>/test/00hbgelokd2i5nglv6opbte003gorrnahv65uo81</Key>
```

Answer (score 1):

Object keys in S3 do not begin with a `/`.

The key for the object at `http://example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/foo/bar.txt` is `foo/bar.txt`, not `/foo/bar.txt`.

So, in your example,  `"/test/"+k.key` should be  `"test/"+k.key`.